MariaDB - Event creation based on subquery
I'm getting crazy trying to set up an event in my MariaDB.
Basically I have a view (BILANCIO_MESE_CONTABILE) which calculate the current available balance based on expences and entries, starting from the balance available at the begin of the month.
Since months for me start on 15th (which I set in the field "GIORNO" of table "GIORNO_INIZIO_MESE"), I'm trying to create an event that occurs every month, when curday() is GIORNO_INIZIO_MESE.GIORNO -1 at 23.59.00, and runs a procedure that inserts a new row in table "BILANCI" where "SALDO_INIZIALE" will be actual "SALDO_FINALE" (final balance from current month).
I keep getting various errors in my event creation; can please someone help to understand what's wrong or suggest another way to accomplish same thing.
THANKS!!!
EVENT CREATION:
DELIMITER //

CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `Esegui_AggiornaSaldoIniziale`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MONTH
STARTS TIMESTAMP(
    LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL (SELECT GIORNO - 1 FROM GIORNO_INIZIO_MESE LIMIT 1) DAY
    + INTERVAL '23:59:00' HOUR_MINUTE
)
DO
BEGIN
    CALL AGGIORNA_SALDO_INIZIALE();
END //

DELIMITER ;

THIS IS THE PROCEDURE (AGGIORNA_SALDO_INIZIALE) which works as charm when I exec it manually.
INSERT INTO BILANCI (MESE_CONTABILE, SALDO_INIZIALE)
SELECT 
   MESE_CONTABILE + 1 AS MESE_CONTABILE,
   BILANCIO_MESE_CONTABILE.SALDO_FINALE AS SALDO_INIZIALE
FROM 
   BILANCIO_MESE_CONTABILE;


Can you clarify which database you're using? You said both MySQL and MariaDB. These are two different products, and they are not compatible. Query SELECT VERSION(); and tell us exactly what it returns.

What error are you getting?

@Barmar #1970 - CREATE/ALTER EVENT does not support subqueries or stored functions

@BillKarwin 10.3.32-MariaDB

I suspected that was the problem. The START and END timestamps have to be simple expressions, you can't use dynamic subqueries like that.

Maybe you can use a variable: SET @giorno = (SELECT GIORNO - 1 FROM GIORNO_INIZIO_MESE LIMIT 1) then use @giorno in the CREATE EVENT statement.

BTW, LIMIT without ORDER BY is asking for trouble.

you mean before the create event?
Like `DELIMITER //
SET @giorno = (SELECT GIORNO - 1 FROM GIORNO_INIZIO_MESE LIMIT 1)
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS Esegui_AggiornaSaldoIniziale
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MONTH
STARTS TIMESTAMP(
LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL @giorno DAY
+ INTERVAL '23:59:00' HOUR_MINUTE
)
....`

@Barmar from the context, this is a one-row table.  settings often get stored like that

I'd suggest dynamic sql for this, but to do a dynamic CREATE EVENT requires 10.6.2 or better.  that said, 10.3 reached end of life almost a year ago and no longer receives security updates; treat it as insecure and plan to upgrade as soon as possible, to the current stable 11.3 or a long term support release 10.11 or 10.6

@ysth If there's only one row, there's no need for LIMIT 1.

@ysth Can't install that versione on my Synology Nas unfortunately.

google tells me they added 10.11 recently, but only for DSM7.  but it sounds like DSM6 won't be supported after this year
